# Creating a char* from a char and an int

Tags: c, char

Is there anyway that I can combine a char and and int and make it into a char* in C?

There would always be only a single char and a 4 digit int.

Eg:
I have the char "A" and I have an int 1234.
How do I combine them into a char* that points to a char array with "A1234" ?

```
CID[0] = character 
CID[1] = ID & 0xff;
CID[2] = (ID >> 8) & 0xff;
CID[3] = (ID >> 16) & 0xff;
CID[4] = (ID >> 24) & 0xff;
```

assuming character is a proper char with "A" as its value and ID is an proper int with "1234" as its value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basic string formatting:

```
char buf[32];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%c%d", 'A', 1234);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer again. Seems like I always see you answering my questions. Something similar, what if I wanted to create a char with "123.345" instead? As in 2 int(s) with a "." in the middle. I tried "%d%c%d" but that doesn't work.

Comment: @user1043625 From what kind of data would you like to get that string? (Also, please google these, if I'm answering questions like this too often, it's likely that you haven't read enough of the standard library documentation.)

Comment: basically I'm combining 2 ints with a "." separating them. I'm looking at the snprintf documentation and I expected "%d%c%d" to work. But instead of giving 123.345 it got 12345. Nvm, got it to work with "%d.%d". Thanks

Comment: @user1043625 Both `"%d.%d", 123, 345` and `"%d%c%d", 123, '.', 345` should work. Are you using one of them?

Answer (score 3):

With `sprintf` / `snprintf` functions.

Example with `sprintf`:

```
char *a = malloc(32);  // allocate enough memory and check malloc's return value 
sprintf(a, "%c%d", my_char, my_int);
```

Comment: Please don't `sprintf()`! It will cause buffer overflows one day.

Comment: You mean the one day when `int` will be 128-bit?

Comment: when the buffer size changes to something that is not enough. (Same reason why `malloc(sizeof *p)` is preferred over `malloc(sizeof TYPE)`.)

Answer (score 2):

To copy what  you wrote in your question and to get away from the `s(n)printf` issue:

```
CID[0] = character 
CID[1] = ID / 1000;
CID[2] = (ID / 100) % 10;
CID[3] = (ID / 10) % 100;
CID[4] = ID % 10;
```

If your compiler is smart enough and your processor has a good divider unit it will be certainly faster than a call to `sprintf`.

EDIT: A little clarification on the compiler smartness and divider goodness. Compilers often are able to transform multiplications and divisions by constants to alternative code using shifting, adding, subtracting and avoiding so a division instruction, which even in the fastest processors still take some time. 
The explicit conversion shown here will also be made inside the `sprintf` (in a more generic way though).

Comment: +1 because this is smart, still I must admit it's extremely ugly.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

buf [SIZE];
sprintf(buf, "%c%d", c, d);
```

When `c` and `d` are your char and int.

Be careful of buffer overflows, though. H2CO3's answer shows a safer alternative.

Comment: From now on, I am going to downvote all answers that misuse `sprintf()`. I start with this one.

Comment: And I upvoted that answer. This is a case where a `sprintf` is sufficient. With the proper SIZE (>20) that function *can not* overflow and sprintf is still more portable than snprintf. Furthermore, `snprintf` without overflow checking is not good either, because it only covers up a bug

Comment: still keeping watch of this question, @H2CO3, :)?

Comment: @tristopia "With the proper SIZE" - yes, exactly. And we're humans and we make mistakes and we put in a too small buffer. Better be safe than risk a stack corruption, right? Hammering out `sizeof(buf)` should not hurt your fingers.

Comment: @DimaRudnik Ah yes, just answered to that comment. (Don't take me wrong - the downvote is **not** against you.)

Comment: @H2CO3, the `sizeof` may not hurt my fingers, and the subsequent `sscanf` (to check the validity of what's in the buffer) may not either... but careful planning may avoid both the bug and the extra check, so I still say use `sscanf` if you know the maximum size of the result.

Comment: @H2CO3, given everything that's been said, seems an unwarrented downvote. Especially considering your first comment saying "I'll make an example out of you, I will!" :)

Comment: @DimaRudnik Again: I didn't want to harrass you, but I'm really pissed off when one suggests *beginners* using unsafe things. I removed my downvote, but please think a bit about the pedagogical significance of your answers next time.